# getting average value from records sql

Tags: sql

I am writing an app that is basically a survey and I've written almost everything but this last part where I need to get stats from the survey.
The table looks like this:

```
user_id|question_id|answer
```

I need to get the average for each answer while still knowing which question ID that average value is associated with. Keep in mind that there can be multiple answers for the same question and multiple and multiple questions with the same answer. The only thing unique is the user_id. The database is Oracle but im sure I can adapt the query if needed. Just need some help with getting started.

Comment: Can you post what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question.

```
Select avg (answer), question_id 
From table 
Group By question_id
```